# Clearing the field of File Upload Control

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Can any one pf you please tell me how to clear the File upload control value using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

function ClearFileUpload()

    {

    var fil = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");

   fil.select(); 

   n=fil.createTextRange(); 

   n.execCommand('delete'); 

   fil.focus();

    }

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons there is no direct access to the value of a file upload control on the client using javascript.

What you could to is deleting the element out of the dom and recreating it. Have a look at this 
[link](http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/) for an example

Comment: we canm clear the file upload control text field. Try the code given in the next answer. I have achieved my expectation through that script.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="uploadFile_div">

           <input type="file" id="uploadFile" onkeydown="return false;" size="40" name="uploadFile"/>

</div>

<a onclick="clearFileInputField('uploadFile_div')" href="javascript:noAction();">Clear</a>


<script>

function clearFileInputField(tagId)

{

   document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;

}

</script>
```

**working code tested IE,Firefox**

Answer (score 0):

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSignatory", "LabMaster", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "Signatory" }))
   { %>
<div>
</div>
<div id="divUpload">
    <input type="file" name="filUpload" accept="image/*" id="filUpload" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" />
</div>
<img id="imgprvw" alt="uploaded image preview" height="200" width="200" />
<input type="button" id="btnRemoveUpload" value="Remove Upload Image" onclick="clearFileInputField('divUpload')"  />
<input type="button" onclick="saveData()" />
<%}%>

  function clearFileInputField(tagId) {

        document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML =

            document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;

    }
```